# graph api restfb - post link of fanpage with link preview

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I would like to know how or if its possible to post a fan page link (using restfb) making it look exactly as the preview that facebook gives in its page, the one that's showing profile photo, cover photo, name of page, likes and some people that liked the page.

i know how to make a link post providing image, title,and description, but im asking for a way to have the same preview that facebook shows when you post directly in their page

sorry for my english hope you can understand what i mean xD, thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a possibility to get the preview, afaik the link preview is even device dependent.

Comment: U_U well i guess the normal one will have to suffice, thank you